# HTML tables column width unification in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to unify two `tables` in JavaScript.
I am doing this because one table contains the other table's headers.
Or maybe there is any other way to do so?

I have:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>ID</td>
  <td>Model</td>
  <td>Brand</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>BMW</td>
  <td>320</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>Audi</td>
  <td>A4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>Some_kind_of_car</td>
  <td>Very_long_name_to_exist</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Thing is that column width in table two is defined by the length of input text there.
And I need it that header length would be the same of table one.

Comment: you can give same width for both table....@justin

Comment: I need that column width would be defined by length of text in that column....

Comment: You can do that using javascript.

Comment: Ya I know I can do that, but how to do that?

Comment: Have a look at this one http://plnkr.co/edit/KIgzVVnbqjbUyqoeW9Qw?p=preview

Comment: AS I said I need two seperate tables, not one.

Answer (score 1):

In javaScript

```
var innerTable = document.getElementById('myTable');
var headerTable = document.getElementById('header');
var totalColumn = headerTable.rows[0].cells.length;

for (var i = 0; i < totalColumn; i++) {
    var innerTableWidth = innerTable.rows[0].cells[i].offsetWidth
    var headerTableWidth = headerTable.rows[0].cells[i].offsetWidth
    if (innerTableWidth < headerTableWidth)
    innerTable.rows[0].cells[i].width = headerTableWidth;
    else
    headerTable.rows[0].cells[i].width = innerTableWidth;

}
```

HTML is

```
<table id="header">
    <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Model</td>
        <td>Brand</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>BMW</td>
        <td>320</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Audi</td>
        <td>A4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Some_kind_of_car</td>
        <td>Very_long_name_to_exist</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[SEE DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/jhaRoshan/hgzgtbac/2/)

Comment: Here is a version that I made, but Roshan was faster: http://jsfiddle.net/thijs_s/q621hxgn/1/ . It shows how to include padding/borders as well.

Comment: yes I forgot to add padding/border. Your fiddle solution is better then me.Should have posted it as answer.